# How do I use pathfinder to make the NPC chase a player

Tags: lua, roblox

I already tried looking up multiple solutions in the Roblox developer forums, but I only found some unfinished code or some code that didn't work with mine. The code in this picture makes my rig find the part and chase it until it's there. That works perfectly, but I've been trying to find a way for the rig to chase the nearest player instead. I've heard of magnitude, but I'm not sure how to implement it, I cant even make the rig chase a player in the first place.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, `.magnitude` is the "length of a vector". It is mostly used to find the distance in vector units from pointA to pointB. Hence, the distance from the 2 points would be `(pointA.Position-pointB.Position).magnitude`.
https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Magnitude

Now in order to chase the players, you can loop through all of the players and get the one your NPC will chase.

You can use a for loop and loop through `game.Players:GetPlayers()` then get their character: `<v>.Character` and then their HumanoidRootPart which has their position. If you wanted to have a range for your NPC or an 'aggro distance', this is where you can implement magnitude. You would first create a variable for your distance. Since we will be dealing with vector units, it should be in length of vectors. For example `local aggroDistance = 30`. When added to the code, this would mean that it would only track a player if they are within 30 studs. You would then put an if statement saying `if (<NPC.HumanoidRootPart.Position-<players hrp position>).magnitude < aggroDistance then`. Now you could use Pathfinding Service to move the NPC to the player by using `PathfindingService:ComputeAsync(<NPC HumanoidRootPart Position, <player HumanoidRootPart Position>)` `:ComputeAsync()` makes a path from the starting position (the first parameter) to the end position (the second parameter). `<NPC Humanoid>:MoveTo(<player HumanoidRootPart Position>)` then makes the NPC move to the player. In order to listen out for when the NPC has reached the end of the path it made in `:ComputeAsync()` you can do `<NPC Humanoid>:MoveToFinished:Connect(function())` to run a function after it reached the end, or `<NPC Humanoid>:MoveToFinished:Wait()` to wait before computing the next path.

**Tip:** You might also want to check if the player has more than 0 health (if they are alive) so the NPC only moves to players who are alive. You can do this by adding a `and <player>.Humanoid.Health > 0` in the if statement where you had your aggroDistance.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Code Makeup:
`aggroDistance variable` < optional
`while loop`
`if statement (can contain aggroDistance variable if you have one) and check player health`
`:ComputeAsync()`
`:MoveTo()`
`:MoveToFinished`
`if statement end`
`while loop end`

Comment: its working and its actually chasing me now!!! Thank you for your help!! However, I found another issue which I can't seem to fix. Ill make another post for it

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you one more time but I have one more question. It's about my rig, which is working perfectly thanks to your knowledge and a few others, but it's always lagging. I'm planning on making us e of your knowledge for aggro after I'm done fixing this dum dum lag. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342588/my-rig-is-always-constantly-lagging-even-though-i-tried-almost-every-solution