# My rig is always constantly lagging even though I tried almost every solution

Tags: lua, roblox

**TL;DR at the bottom**

Good evening/afternoon/morning, I am trying to create a simple maze-horror game, and right now I'm trying to code my enemy. I used this rig to try to make my own custom enemy, https://www.roblox.com/library/5025299499/R15-Character-Template

I am using pathfinder to make my NPC chase the enemy which is working perfectly, except for the fact that it's constantly glitching/lagging. I tried every way possible, from refusing to use "humanoid.MoveToFinished", and using the code below instead. I also tried making the HumaoidRootPart be set to, "SetNetworkOwner(nil)". The only thing I haven't tried is to set ALL my parts in the rig too, "SetNerworkOwner(nil)", but I have NO idea on how to do that. I tried looping through all the parts, but I dont even know how to set each part that I looped through to, "SetNetworkOwner(nil). I also made and added custom parts into each body part of the rig, as you can see from the picture below. Please help me out, I really appreciate it.

**TL;DR**: I created an enemy using a template, I successfully used pathfinder, but it's just always lagging, even with all my efforts to stop the lag.

[image]

[image]

[image: I added custom parts into each body part of the rig]

Comment: Please provide your code as text, not image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the `repeat until` loop as the `distance` variable doesn't seem to be used in the code.

Here would be the code structure:
`Variable defining`
`Begin while loop`
`Player for loop`
`if statement to check player distance` < optional. If you do this, you need a variable for max distance for the NPC to follow a player. This variable should be made in the 'Variable defining' section
`:CreatePath() and :ComputeAsync()`
`end for loop`
`:GetWaypoints()`
`start new for loop to loop through waypoints`
`<Humanoid>:MoveTo(<v>.Position)`
`<Humanoid>:MoveToFinished:Wait(0.1)` < Highly recommended. This gives the script enough time to create and compute another path
`end for loop`
`end if statement`
`end while loop`

Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Wait I think I need to edit my answer, hold on

Comment: I've already created lines for :CreatePath() and :ComputeAsync() in lines 13 & 14. Those are fine to keep right? According to the template you provided it makes sense to me but I don't really know. Lastly, for line 25, I'm not sure what to set the parameter in MoveTo() to, because I deleted the for loop.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that, ur a legend!!

Comment: I've edited my answer. Try the updated version and see if it works. Keep :ComputeAsync() and :CreatePath() as well as :GetWaypoints(). I think the lag in your right might have been caused by 1. the repeat until loop (you can delete it) and 2. there was no wait between moving to waypoints, so add a :MoveToFinished:Wait()

Comment: im sorry I have one more question, when you stated how I should :GetWaypoints() after the for loop ends, I'm not sure how to do that. When I'm creating the variable for :GetWayPoints() it requires a variable that's inside the first for loop(line 13). Do I just make the variable global?

Comment: make a normal variable like: `local waypoints = <PathfindingService>:GetWaypoints()` then loop though the waypoints by doing `for _, v in pairs(waypoints) do` and use `<humanoid>:MoveTo(v.Position)` in the for loop to move the humanoid to each for loop

Comment: alright, thank you once again!!! You helped me a lot!!

Comment: im sorry I have ONE MORE question, in the local waypoints = <PathfindingService>:GetWaypoints(), what do I put in place <PathfindingService>? Im having a lot of trouble with that.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. That's just what you defined as `game:GetService("PathfindingService")`, so in your case, it would be `PathFindingS:GetWaypoints()`

Comment: Oh no problem for the late reply, you don't have to worry. I believe I did already try that last night, but it was showing some sort of error. I will update my post to include the error after I wake up and get ready, but I believe it was trying to say that I can do that with the path finding service variable.

Comment: When I try doing "local waypoints = PathFindingS:GetWaypoints()", it shows an error saying, "GetWaypoints is not a valid member of PathfindingService "Instance"".

Comment: Make sure you are going `game:GetService("PathfindingService")` and not `Instance.new("PathfindingService")` when you define it at the top of your script

Comment: yeah, that's what I did, I kept it the same as the picture of my code shown above, but it still shows that error.